# Auto resize div according to screen resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am am using bootstrap. I have header i want that header div remain fixed in their postion just text size reduce or according to large "lg",small "sm" medium "md" and xtra small "xs".

**This is my code**

**CSS:**

```
     body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #333;
        background-color: #B96060;
     }
    .header{
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid black;
     }
```

**HTML:**

```
   <body >
  <div class="row header">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-lg-3 ">
                <img  src="../images/logo_icon.png"   border="0"                                   class="img-responsive"  >    
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <center><h2 nowrap>Bury pakk public school</h2><center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 ">
                        <p>Logout</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ">
                        <p>user : Khan</p>
                        <p>Access Level : Khan<p>
            </div>
        </div>  

      </div>
    </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try  font-size:8vmin; (change value according to your need)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `'navbar-fixed-top'` class with `.header` class.

and for font size, `you can assign font in`em`insted of`px,
font size will reduce as per size of the device. 
The font size will change only when you you will write media query for body font-size.
suppose default font-size is 14px and in media query max-width 767px if you ve written 12px for body. 
in that condition all em font will shrink to some percent.

Comment: using `em` will not change font size as per size of the device.

Comment: Ya i know, for that you have to write media query, I ve not mentioned ,

Comment: pixels work in media query too, there is no need to change them to `em` then.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you made a mistake.

- First rows must be inside the container not outside
- Whenever you want to wide a column you must define `<div class = row>` again

Your css will look something like this

```
 <div class="container header">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 ">
                <img  src="../images/logo_icon.png"   border="0"                                   class="img-responsive"  >    
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <center><h2 nowrap>Bury pakk public school</h2><center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 ">
                        <p>Logout</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ">
                        <p>user : Khan</p>
                        <p>Access Level : Khan<p>
            </div>
        </div>  
       </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

For the second part,many ways to do it. Use media querires, to change size of text according to screen size rendered rendered. Here is code directly from the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

```
 /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
  .header{
        font-size: 0.4em;
   }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { 
     .header{
        font-size: 0.7em;
   }
 }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
  .header{
        font-size: 1em;
   } 
 }
```

**I advice that you go through bootstrap docs,or you end up with more mistakes**

Comment: This is not workin. Actualy i want that  my header detail remain same in all devices. My all div wil remain in same postion instead of changing postion. i.e shift from to row to column view

Comment: I made changes check it out